# passing mysqli to function does not work as expected

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been coding in php for about 1 and half month. To query databse I usually pass the `$mysqli` to the function from where I am calling. I include the db.php there from where I am calling. The code works sometimes and fails sometimes without any reason. I wrote a page and inluded some functionality there. It worked for thousands of time as I am developing. right now it stopped passing the `$mysqli` object and the code in function started complaining and there is no reason why. I did not change anything. 
It happened on many occasion that when I pass `$mysqli` it is not sure whether it will be passed or not. What is the problem with this?f

```
function getsubjectname($mysqli, $subjectid)
    {
        $query="select SubjectName from user_subject where SubjectId=?";
        $stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $subjectid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($SubjectName);
        $stmt->fetch();
        return $SubjectName;

    }
```

in the code above it was recieving the $mysqli object until now. But now it can't see it. 
when I include the `$mysqli=new MySQLi('localhost','root','','spiralblog');` in the function itself then it works.

**Edit**

```
<div style='font-size:24px;'> 
<?php if(!isset($_GET['subjectid']))
{
    $row=getpinnedsubject($mysqli, $userid); echo $row['SubjectName']; 
} else {  
echo getsubjectname($mysqli, $_GET['subjectid']);
}?>
</div>
```

This code is on the index.php and the calling function is in another page. dedicated to functions

Comment: Think we might need more info. Code snippet of where the function is used. Also why no `if(isset($mysqli)){ echo "No SQL Object"; }`?

Comment: @Twisty I think your `if` needs a `!` and a `return` ;)

Comment: mysqli object:  is it included at the top of your script example: include_once 'includes/db_connect.php'; // where ever you have it

Comment: @Careen ... Yes I have included it.. as I said it was working so far just suddenly stopped working

Comment: @Twisty I have included some more code

Comment: @Twisty I included the `isset` and it says the object is set...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the header page that I included in the homepage, I did a query there and did not close the `stmt` object afterwards. That was causing the unexpected behaviour. So should close the `stmt` always. :)